# why am i not getting the state in my application

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

am a newbie in redux, am trying to add an item to the basket but am getting, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState'). why am i not able to get the state is there something i need to do that am not doing, please what am i not doing properly. am using useDispatch hook to read the store and dispatch the action

hey is my code

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
}

export const basketSlice = createSlice({
    name: "basket",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addToBasket: (state, action) => {
            state.items = [...state.items, action.payload]
        },
        removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {},
    }
});

export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket} = basketSlice.actions;
export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;
export default basketSlice.reducer;



import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import basketReducer from "../slices/basketSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        basket: basketReducer,
    },
});

import '../styles/globals.css'
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../app/store'

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </SessionProvider>
    </Provider>  
  )
}

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {addToBasket} from "../slices/basketSlice"

const Product = ({id, title, description, price, image, category }) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const addItemToBasket = () => {
          const product = {
            id,
            title, 
            description, 
            price, 
            image, 
            category 
          }

          dispatch(addToBasket(product))
      }

  return (
    <div className="relative flex flex-col m-10 p-10 bg-white rounded-3xl">
        <button onClick={addItemToBasket} className=" button">Add to basket</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: What does the code for your component with the add/remove buttons look like? Are you using the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks to read from the store and dispatch actions?

Comment: am using dispatch

Comment: i just update the code, please you can go through it again. thank you

Comment: Thanks for updating. What about the component where you're reading from the store and displaying it? It should look something like: `const items = useSelector((state) => state.basket.items)`. See [this example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#use-redux-state-and-actions-in-react-components).

Comment: i exported it by putting it in a variable called selectItems, this is how it look like in the basketSlice component: `export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items`

Comment: Try displaying the items with the `useSelector` hook, e.g., `const items = useSelector(selectItems)` then `console.log(items)` whenever you add/remove to see if it's working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243185/discussion-between-jonuel-and-mark-g).

Comment: thank you for trying to help me out but is still showing thesame error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the state isn't being set inside the `<Provider />` component correctly. Your `store` is a named export, but it's being imported into `_app.js` as if it were a `default` export (without curly braces). Try using `import { store } from "../some_path_to_store"` instead.

Here's a working example to conclude our discussion from the comment section:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-fire-o3tr54

Comment: thank you so much, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Either return NEW state from action reducer:

```
        addToBasket: (state, action) => {
            return { ...state, items: [...state.items, action.payload] }
        },
```

or MODIFY existing state without replacing it. And don't return anything:

```
        addToBasket: (state, action) => {
          state.items.push(action.payload)
        },
```

also, in your example provide a type information for an action:

```
action: PayloadAction<type_of_item>
```

Comment: am not using typescript